# Deploying Custom Report Type with Activities via Change Set odd behavior

Tags: custom-report-type

We have a couple of custom report types that I edited in Sandbox to add a new field to the Activities Layout so I could use that field in Reports. I deployed these custom report types via change set into Production. However, the Activities relationship is now missing when it was deployed in Prod(note: the only change I did was to add the new custom field).

This is the report type in **SANDBOX:**

[image]

This is the report type after change set is deployed in **PRODUCTION:**

[image]

Looks like change set is not picking up the Activities relationship when I checked the metadata in my Outbound Change Set. Anybody else who experienced the same? Is this an expected behavior or a bug or something else? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have person-account enabled?

Comment: Hi @Tsmith, no, we don't user person accounts.